# How to fix ProgrammingError when exporting pandas dataframe to a sql server?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I encounter a programming error when trying to perform dataframe to sql.

```py
import pymysql 

import sqlalchemy

database_username = 'myname'
database_password = 'password'
database_ip       = 'some host:port'
database_name     = 'myname'
database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.
                                               format(database_username, database_password, 
                                                      database_ip, database_name), pool_recycle=1, pool_timeout=57600).connect()

DF.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='IOS', schema=None, if_exists='replace', index=False, index_label=None, dtype=None)
```

I expect data to be exported to the remote database.
The actual result is:
I was told that there is a syntax error, but the insert clause and parameters seem to make perfect sense to me....

```
ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) 
(1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '5bf27ed941f800ea780c2c5425ca1c96''),
(b''cfca791b5a1e18af1724ae8d42e85ee0''),
(b''' at line 1") 
[SQL: u'INSERT INTO `IOS` (`MD5`) VALUES (%(MD5)s)'] 
[parameters: 
({'MD5': '5bf27ed941f800ea780c2c5425ca1c96'}, 
{'MD5': 'cfca791b5a1e18af1724ae8d42e85ee0'},
 {'MD5': '4cb1e3d62ff5a96628fa97f1e966f723'}, 
{'MD5': '9e35c083694bd8fd12e5c229c2a0008c'}, 
{'MD5': '4bba3f25817cff7c441d13e3bc5ace5e'})]
```

I find that I could export certain kinds of dataframes in the code I use above, however it doesn't work for dataframe generated by bigquery result. This is what in the dataframe DF refered in the code above:

```py
%bq query -n md5query
SELECT id, MD5
FROM `dataset.IOS` 

MD5 = md5query.execute().result().to_dataframe()
DF = MD5['MD5']
```

Comment: Are you writing the other DataFrames that *do work* into the same table (I guess not)? Or does it only fail for this one? Does the table already exist before you execute? Did sqlalchemy create the table, what are the types of the columns?

Comment: What is the MD5 column type in `dataset.IOS`? Is it a VARCHAR? Have you allocated enough memory? Are you sure the value in the `DataFrame` matches? (You can use `DataFrame.dtypes` to confirm.)